# Unexpected behaviour of SELECT query after UPDATE

Tags: java, mysql

Following is the logic in my java code :

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
int starIndex = 0;
List Details = new ArrayList();

    while (true) {
                    isRsEmpty = true;
                    String my_Query = "select * from x,y,z where"
                            + " x.a = y.b"
                            + " x.a = z.c"
                            + "y.b = z.e"
                            + " ORDER BY a ASC"
                            + " limit 5"
                            + " offset " + starIndex;


                    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(my_Query);
                    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        isRsEmpty = false;

               //Other processing steps


                        starIndex++;
                        Details.add(rs.getInt("id"));
                    }

                    if(isRsEmpty){
                        starIndex = 0;
                    }


                    Iterator itr = Details.iterator();
                    String updateTable = "UPDATE x SET status = ? where i = ? and j = ? and k = ?";
                    updatePreparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(updateTable);

                    while (itr.hasNext()) {

                        updatePreparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
                        updatePreparedStatement.setString(2, "zzz");
                        updatePreparedStatement.setInt(3, 9);
                        updatePreparedStatement.setInt(4, 10);
                        updatePreparedStatement.addBatch();


                    }

                    updatePreparedStatement.executeBatch();
                    con.commit();
                    Details.clear();
    }
```

**The Problem** :

I have 13 entries in my table which meets the select query.

When I first time run the query my Limit is 5 and Offset is 0 and I get 
5 records correctly from the table and the selected 5 records are updated.

After doing the update to the table when the select query runs again it gives me 3 records.**This is unexpected** since I have more 8 records left in the table.Again the 3 records are updated.

Again when the select query runs it gives me 0 records.

Then again a select query runs which gives me  5 records and updates the 5 records.

I am not able to understand this behaviour. If I run my select query without update then it runs correctly which gives me 5,5,3 records , but with the above logic it gives me 5,3,0,5 records.

What is the problem here ?

Note : In the above program all the variables like PreparedStatement and other are declared correctly.

Thank you

Comment: it's because you are missing p,q,r

Comment: Why don't you selected everything and limit you batch to 5 loop before executing ? Please, provide something that can be reproduce, add a sample with table structure, ...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you are missing "and" keyword between your conditions in the select query?

```
String my_Query = "select * from x,y,z where"
                        + " x.a = y.b"
                        + " AND x.a = z.c"
                        + " AND y.b = z.e"
                        + " ORDER BY a ASC"
                        + " limit 5"
                        + " offset " + starIndex;
```

I don't know if that would solve the problem but I find it weird that it works like this.